# Ionic 4 - Ion-footer goes transparent when ion-refresh is used

Tags: css, ionic4

I tried adding a ion-refresher to my app, but when i pull to refresh, the ion-footer goes transparent.

Code:

```
<ion-content padding color="primary">
    <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
        <ion-refresher-content color="primary" pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown" pullingText="Pull to refresh" refreshingSpinner="circles" refreshingText="Refreshing...">
        </ion-refresher-content>
      </ion-refresher>
    <div *ngFor="let weather of weather_data">
.......
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar color="white">
    <div class="tabs">
      <div class="tab">
        <ion-icon name="keypad"></ion-icon>
        <div class="label">Input</div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
        <div class="label">Account</div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon>
        <div class="label">Log Out</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, i just removed the color attribute in the footer. Thanks anyway